# Could this closed form for negative integer values of a series involving $\zeta(s)$ be proven?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, riemann-zeta, stirling-numbers

The following series expression:

$$f(s) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\zeta(n)-1}{n^s} \tag{1}$$

has well known closed forms for $s=0$ and $s=1$, however also seems to converge for $\Re(s) < 0$. After some experimentation I conjecture that:

$$f(-m) = 1+ \sum_{k=1}^m k!\, \mathrm{Stirling2}(m+1,k+1)\, \zeta(k+1) \tag{2}$$

for $m = 0, 1, 2, 3, ...$ with Stirling2 a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Similarly for the alternating series:

$$g(s) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n\,\frac{\zeta(n)-1}{n^s} \tag{3}$$

I conjecture:

$$g(-m) = -\frac{E_m(2)}{2} - \sum_{k=1}^m (-1)^k \,k!\, \mathrm{Stirling2}(m+1,k+1)\, \zeta(k+1) \tag{4}$$

for $m = 1, 2, 3,...$. With $E_m(2)$ the [m-th Euler Polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerPolynomial.html) evaluated at $2$.

Is this indeed true?

Comment: Your question is confusing as first you indicate that $f(s)$ converges for $R(s)<0$ and then you indicate $f(-m)$ evaluated at $m = 0, -1, -2, -3, ...$ which would seem to correspond to $\Re(s)\ge 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Particular_values) for the polylogarithm $\operatorname{Li}_{-m}(z)$ where $m$ is a nonnegative integer.

$$ \begin{align} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n^{m} \left( \zeta(n)-1 \right) &= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n^{m} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{n}} \\ &= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n^{m}}{k^{n}} \\ &= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left( \operatorname{Li}_{-m} \left(\frac{1}{k} \right) -\frac{1}{k} \right) \\ &= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{m} j! S (m+1,j+1 ) \left(\frac{1}{k-1}\right)^{j+1}-\frac{1}{k}\right) \\ &= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{j=\color{red}{1}}^{m} j! S (m+1,j+1 ) \left(\frac{1}{k-1}\right)^{j+1} + \frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right) \\ &= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{m}j! S (m+1,j+1 ) \left(\frac{1}{k-1}\right)^{j+1} + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k} \right) \\ &= \sum_{j=1}^{m} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}j! S (m+1,j+1 ) \left(\frac{1}{k-1}\right)^{j+1} + 1 \\ &= \sum_{j=1}^{m}j! S (m+1,j+1 ) \zeta(j+1)+1 \end{align}$$

---

Using the same approach for the alternating version, I get $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} n^{m} \left(\zeta(n)-1 \right) = \sum_{j=1}^{m} (-1)^{j+1} j! S(m+1,j+1) \left(\zeta(j+1)-1-\frac{1}{2^{j+1}} \right) + \frac{1}{2},$$ which seems to give correct values.

Comment: Very nice, that solves it!

Comment: I've checked the alternating version and can confirm it yields the correct values. The Euler polynomials evaluated at $2$ could probably be reproduced from the last two terms in the sum and the $\frac12$.

Comment: @Agno   Does equation $(4)$ have a typo? For example, for the case $m=4$, it looks like you need to add $1$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%28-1%29%5En*n%5E4*%28zeta%28n%29-1%29+from+n%3D2+to+infinity), [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F2%2B+%28sum+1.0*%28-1%29%5E%28j%2B1%29*j%21*StirlingS2%5B4%2B1%2Cj%2B1%5D*%28zeta%28j%2B1%29-1-1%2F2%5E%28j%2B1%29%29+from+j%3D+1+to+4%29), and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-EulersE%5B4%2C2%5D-+%28sum+%28-1%29%5Ek*k%21*StirlingS2%5B4%2B1%2Ck%2B1%5D*zeta%28k%2B1%29+from+k%3D1+to+4%29).

Comment: Yes, well spotted. The euler polynomial should have been divided by $2$. I will correct it in the OP.